Formula If value in column starts with digit "66" returns "ASIA", if starts with "EU" return "Europa", if value/cell is empty/blanks return"canceled"
Based on values in column - PackingList, I wish to create another column with values:
Asia, Europe, Cancelled.  If value starts with digit "66" wish to return in new column "Asia",
if starts with anything else than 66 return "Europe" but if no value on PackingList wish to return string "Cancelled".
Dont know where to add statement about blank. Here what I have done do far"
Column = VAR _startwith = LEFT(Query2[PACKLIST_ID]) RETURN IF(_startwith IN {"66"},"Europa","Asia")

Please support.
TIA

You could use the SWITCH function. Its last argument, being an unmatched Result/Value acts as an ELSE.
Column = VAR _startwith = LEFT(Query2[PackingList],2) 
RETURN SWITCH(_startwith,"66","ASIA","","Canceled","Europa")



You need to extract the first two characters from PACKLIST_ID to check if it starts with 66 and if the PACKLIST_ID column is blank, returning "Cancelled" if true.
If the value is not blank, it checks if it starts with 66, returning "Asia" if true; otherwise, it returns "Europe".
Column = 
VAR _startwith = LEFT(Query2[PACKLIST_ID], 2) 
RETURN 
    IF(
        ISBLANK(Query2[PACKLIST_ID]), 
        "Cancelled", 
        IF(
            _startwith = "66", 
            "Asia", 
            "Europe"
        )
    )

You can also use :
Column = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ISBLANK(Query2[PACKLIST_ID]), "Cancelled",
    LEFT(Query2[PACKLIST_ID], 2) = "66", "Asia",
    "Europe"
)

